# How to calculate observation error in RPC model

Tags: orthorectification

I'm implementing the RPC model for geometric correction of images. I've done the calculation of coefficients from the polynomial model, but I want to implement one with better numerical stability, such as the iterative and direct least-squares solutions.

I based my work on the original paper describing the RPC method - *"Comprehensive Study of the
Rational Function Model for
Photogrammetric Processing"* authors: Tao and Hu. To be specific - I don't know how to calculate/find the **r** parameter in **(5a.)** equation or respectively the **R** matrix in **(8)** equation in this paper.

Answer (score 2):

**r** means rows.

I'm sorry for that useless question.